# How to change navigation column to be used in ASPNetCore EF scaffolding

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, scaffolding

I am using code first with EF6 and AspNetCore to create hundreds of tables and views using the scaffold templates.

In simple navigation models

```
    public class BaseModel 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(100)")]
        public string? BaseModelNo { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SubModel>? SubModels { get; set; } 

    }
    public class SubModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(100)]
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(100)")]
        public string? SubModelNo { get; set; }
 
        public int BaseModelId { get; set; }
        public virtual BaseModel? BaseModelNo { get; set; }

    }
```

When scaffolding, the controller:

```
        ...
            ViewData["BaseModelId"] = new SelectList(_context.BaseModels, "Id", "Id", model.BaseModelId);
            return View();
        ...
```

and in Details Views

```
        ...
        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BaseModel.Id)
        </dd>
        ...
```

***My Question is***
Is there a way to let it instead bind automatically to the first property that is not the primary key, `Id`, which in this example should be `BaseModelNo`

So in the controller:

```
        ...
            ViewData["BaseModelId"] = new SelectList(_context.BaseModels, "Id", "BaseModelNo", model.BaseModelId);
            return View();
        ...
```

and in Details Views

```
        ...
        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BaseModel.BaseModelNo)
        </dd>
        ...
```

What I tried: Changing the order of the model

Comment: I further tried and tested [DefaultBindingProperty] and other attributes which enables you to retrieve the property from code, so I  could change the scaffold template to return that column instead. This was not very productive

Comment: Then I realized that I did not have this problem in one of my other developments.

Comment: It turns out to be very simple. Simply add empty project to the solution. Then move the Models folder to that project and add project a reference . The scaffolder will automatically bind to the first non nullable string property in the model. It works, but can someone explain to my why that is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who had this issue or find it interesting, I posted the source
on gihub at [here](https://github.com/CConXAdmin/WebApplication5)

I would still like someone to explain why it works this way, but for now, it works, by simply having the model in a seperate project.

[image: movel model to new project]

In my example, the entities in Models.cs scaffold binds to Id, where as the entities in OtherModels.cs scaffolds binds to the first non nullable string property.

```
    public class OtherBase
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Name1 { get; set; }
        public string Name2 { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<OtherSub> OtherSub { get; set; }
    }
```

So in this case will bind to Name2.